# LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Tags: android, xml

My original layout xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/app"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0px"
android:background="#e4e8ed"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0px" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/tabBar"
    layout="@layout/tab" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/nist"
    android:layout_width="301dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:text="Generate NIST file" />

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rectangle"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But if I move the `Button` beneath the inner `LinearLayout` my app is just throwing an exception:

```
LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

I think this is weird, how can I manage to do so?

**EDIT:**

This is the way I "import" the button to my java code:

```
setTabBar(R.layout.horz_scroll_app);
nist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nist);
```

The `setTabBar` method:

```
public void setTabBar(int id) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.horz_scroll_with_list_menu, null);
    setContentView(scrollView);

    menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.horz_scroll_menu, null);

    app = inflater.inflate(id, null);
    ViewGroup tabBar = (ViewGroup) app.findViewById(R.id.tabBar);

    ListView listView = (ListView) app.findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView = (ListView) menu.findViewById(R.id.list);

    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = getMenuItems();
    listView.setAdapter(new MenuCustomAdapter(this, menuItems));

    btnSlide = (ImageButton) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.BtnSlide);
    btnSlide.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                btnSlide.setImageResource(R.drawable.lincolor);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                btnSlide.setImageResource(R.drawable.lin);
                break;
            }

            return false;
        }

    });
    btnSlide.setOnClickListener(new ClickListenerForScrolling(scrollView,
            menu));

    final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };

    int scrollToViewIdx = 1;
    scrollView.initViews(children, scrollToViewIdx,
            new SizeCallbackForMenu(btnSlide));

}
```

I should also mention that this problem occurs ONLY for the `Button` element if I add other elements under the inner `LinearLayout` it works..

Comment: could you post your reference code(JAVA)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try cleaning and rebuilding the project, or restart Eclipse if that doesn't work.

Comment: ADT plugin sometime fails... I also went crazy when this first happened to me

Comment: Son of a gun.  Fixed the problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same problem, what helped me out:

Make sure you do not use the default ID for your view-element (togglebutton, editText, etc).

When you add and remove new elements of the same type in your layout they seem to disturb each other.

So, always use an individual ID.

Answer (score -1):

To be further **extensive** for all of those that may have also missed something obvious in their code (as I did):

Make sure that your java code doesn't literally cast your layout as a button:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected Button LL_vertical; //MISTAKE HERE


    public void someFunction() {

        //R.id.LL_vertical is a linearlayout
        LL_vertical = view.findViewById(R.id.LL_vertical); 

        ...

    }

 ... rest of code ..
}
```

should be

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected LinearLayout LL_vertical; //MISTAKE FIXED

    public void someFunction() {

        //R.id.LL_vertical is a linearlayout
        LL_vertical = view.findViewById(R.id.LL_vertical); 
        
        ...

    }

 ... rest of code ..
}
```